# How to rotate iPad screen using a gesture rather than physically rotating the device

Tags: objective-c, ipad, rotation

Here's my user's iPad requirement.  Two users are sitting down at a table with an iPad between them.  Each user needs the ability to "take control" of the app by doing a gesture to rotate the screen towards him. This would be equivalent to picking up the iPad and changing its rotation to face the user.  A few questions about this:

1) Is there any default behavior within iOS to to be able to do this?

2) Do you know of any apps where this is done so I can see it in action?

3) Lastly, how do I go about enabling this functionality for my app?  This functionality should be available for all UIViewControllers within my app.

Comment: This is to replace rotation according to physical device orientation or to augment it?

Comment: This would be to augment it.  Basically there would 2 ways to rotate it, by physical device orientation and by a gesture (don't know which one yet).  Has anyone seen this functionality used in any apps?

Answer (score 0):

I'm no expert on the topic, but here are my thoughts:

If you want to also have the app respond to device rotations, the proposal is a bit more complicated. However, if you want to eliminate physical device rotation reactions in favor of rotating the app yourself, there are only a few steps necessary:

1. Stop the views from auto-rotating. In **iOS 6**, this is as simple as implementing the `shouldAutorotate:` method and returning `NO` and the `supportedInterfaceOrientations` method to only return the one orientation you want to allow in the view controller at the **root** of your controller hierarchy. In **iOS 5** and earlier, you want to implement the `shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:` to only return `YES` for one orientation in the view controller that is at the **top** of the view controller hierarchy.
2. Add code that reacts to the gesture you want to use to rotate the screen (maybe a gesture recognizer).
3. When the gesture is performed by the user, rotate whichever view is at the bottom of the view hierarchy in your app. Likely, you will rotate the view managed by the `rootViewController`. Remember that you will need to deal with the new size of this view, not just the orientation. To affect the rotation, I think the best route is to apply an affine transform to the view's layer. [This](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=1951182) is pretty helpful if you are not familiar with affine transforms.